# Callable interface

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I have a c++ program that generates large numbers of small graphs (millions). I would like to remove graphs that are isomorphic to each other so I am thinking about trying to use the callable interface to mathematica to do this.
I see there is something called WSTP with essentially string interfaces. I see mentions here of MathLink but that isn't in the list of topics when I look in help so maybe that's an older interface.
I am wondering if it's realistic to call mathematica a large number of times via the WSTP interface to essentially just check if two small graphs are isomorphic.
My graphs are acyclic multi-digraphs with a single source and sink. My notion of isomorphic is a path-edge incidence matrix that is a row and column permutation of another path-edge incidence matrix. So I will generate a kind of line graph that has a vertex for an edge and a vertex for a path and a directed edge if the edge is in the path and test these for isomorphism. Maybe ~100 paths and ~10 edges.
A naive isomorphism test like in boost or my own code is too slow.

Comment: WSTP and MathLink are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 11):

You should not test pairs of graphs for isomorphism, as that is quadratic in the number of graphs, and it's hopeless. You should compute a canonical labelling of each graph with a suitable library (bliss, nauty, traces, etc.—*not* Boost which only has VF2 for testing *pairs* of graphs), then use a set data structure to remove duplicates.

I do not recommend trying to call Mathematica to do this. It will be very slow. I know this as I created [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) and suffered plenty of frustration due to Mathematica's lack of *performant* facilities to convert a `Graph` to/from some format that is friendly to C++. They didn't add this even after years of requests.

Just use a C or a C++ library from your C++ program. It'll be faster than what Mathematica has anyway. I believe Mathematica may be using an old version of nauty.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am familiar with the concept of a canonical labeling. Since I am currently running on Windows I thought mathematica might be the path of least resistance but that doesn't seem likely now. I'll shift to trying to get my program running in the linux subsystem.

Comment: @NeillClift why do you think that running in Linus will improve the difficulty of what you are trying to do now?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your asking. My thinking is that since mathematica doesn't seem to offer functionality I can use for this problem I should probably try and get nauty working. As far as I can see this only runs in unix.

Comment: @NeillClift It's not Unix-specific. If you are going to use an automorphism finder from C++ code, I would recommend Bliss over Nauty: it has an easier to use API.

Comment: Szabolcs, thanks for that suggestion. I got bliss working quite quickly and doing the isomorphism test on my graphs. Looks fast enough for my experiments.